# Cannot pass variable to Laravel x-component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am building a webpage in Laravel 8 using x-components in some places. A component is a modal present in all pages but whose content must change depending on the page invoking it.

My idea was the following:

1. **IndexController** using **PageModel** passes *$pageid* to **index.blade** view
2. **index.blade** passes *$pageid* to **x-insert-section** component
3. **x-insert-section** component uses it in a @switch directive to show the required content per page

The problem is that **x-insert-section** doesn't seem to receive any value in *$pageid*.

The code is the following:

**My IndexController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Page;
use App\Models\Entry;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function init(Request $request)
    {

        $page = Page::where('slug', '/')->first();

        return view('index', [
            'page' => $page,
            'entries' => Entry::where('page', $page->id)->get(),
            'pageid' => $page->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

**The part of index.blade.php where the x-components are loaded**

```
    <x-insert-section :pageid="$pageid"></x-insert-section>
    <x-insert-jumbo-image :pageid="$pageid"></x-insert-jumbo-image>
```

**InsertSection.php Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class InsertSection extends Component
{

    public function __construct(){}

    public $pageid;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.insert-section');
    }
}
```

**The view of the insert-section.blade.php (Switch contents have been replaced by comments to reduce code length)**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="create-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-entry-title"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        @switch($pageid)
            @case('1')
                      <!-- Form type 1 -->
                @break

            @case('3')
                      <!-- Form type 2 -->
                @break

            @default
               Default Case
        @endswitch

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="confirm-entry" type="submit" form="create-form" class="btn btn-primary">{{$pageid}}</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE: I have tried using both '1' and 1 as values for the switch case, even sending harcoded strings, none worked**

Finally, the result on screen when the modal is called. No form is loaded and the switch resolves to default case.

[Screenshot of modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOlCF.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Well it turns out I have the solution after reading the Docs (bless them, damn my poor reading)

The part missing was the contructor receiving the variables, therefore the code changes this way.

**InsertSection.php Component**

**From:**

```
    public function __construct(){}

    public $pageid;
```

**To:**

```
    public $pageid;

    public function __construct($pageid)
    {
        $this->pageid = $pageid;
    }
```

I know I know, makes a lot of sense but I guess I'll remember it for next time.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a variable to the component in Laravel, there are two ways to do this,

1. use @props in a component that doesn't have any controller,
2. But in your code you have a controller, so simply in your controller's constructor initialized your variable.

   public $pageid;

   public function __construct($pageid)
   {
   $this->pageid = $pageid;
   }

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't the second one the same as in the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

Also, please pay attention to https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#casing.

Passing a variable to a component such as $page_id won't work. It should be $pageid or $pageId.